# Filter a certain value in List according to Where using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

assuming i have a list like below:

```
List <Customclass> someList = new List<CustomClass>() 
{
    new CustomClass { color = "Red", type = "lcd" },
    new CustomClass { color = "Red", type = "cvr" },
    new CustomClass { color = "Green", type = "lcd" },
    new Customclass { color = "Green", type = "cvr" },
    new CustomClass { color = "Blue", type = "lcd" },
    new CustomClass { color = "Blue", type = "cvr" }
};
```

how to can i filter the list to only show the `color` value and that the `type` must be `lcd`

something like this in SQL

`SELECT [color] FROM [someList] WHERE [type] = 'lcd';`

and the output would be:

```
Red
Green
Blue
```

i am very new to LINQ as i have no hint on how to do this thing. so i hope someone or anyone can help me here. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like the following:

```
var colors = someList.Where(cc=>cc.type=="lcd")
                     .Select(cc=>cc.color);
```

- Initially, you have to filter your list, using the `Where` method and a predicate that requires that the items in the output sequence should have as a type `lcd`.
- Having filter your list, you have to make a projection using the `Select` method and pick only the `color` of each item of the filtered sequence.

Comment: @TheQuestioner you are welcome :) I am glad that I helped !

Comment: also if i may ask, is the approach the same if i have, let's say 2 or 3 where statements ?. or how would i do it ? thanks :)

Comment: You could write your multiple condition in one `Where` statement like  `Where(cc=>cc.type=="lcd" && cc.color=="Blue")`

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
someList.Where(x=> x.type == "lcd").Select(x=> x.color).ToList();
```

Or

```
var results = (from x in someList
              where x.color == "lcd"
              select x.color).ToList();
```

Comment: Except that doesn't select the color part... Christos's answer is the right one here.

Comment: but how can i display the `color` only ?

Comment: @TheQuestioner i was already editing the answer. You have multiple options and syntaxes to do so. Check it out.

Comment: this is another way or two to do so. i'll keep a note of this too. although Christos was faster. still thanks :)